# Using ListLayout for grouped items inside a ListView with GridLayout

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winjs

Suppose I have a ListView with grouped data and a GridLayout. I'd like to have a vertical list for the items inside a group (each group represented in yellow) and the horizontal list for each group.

Can I do this using a ListView?

[image: foo]

(the arrows represent the expected scrolling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that this sort of combination of scrolling directions is not recommended according to the Windows design principles. A single panning axis gives a user a solid feel as if they're interacting with real content, but combined scrolling tends to disorient. Especially when the user is scrolling with a mouse wheel.
It likely won't fail you in certification, but I thought I'd just give you some food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

You could have nested ListViews: one, which scrolls horizontally and that displays the items from the groupedDataSource as a normal itemDataSource.

Then have the item renderer for the group items create their own ListViews with a vertical ListLayout in which they display the items from their respective group.